# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Substr'

Tags: python

I'm writing a python script to convert data from csv to geojson, which is working.
I have a field in the date format ( "2017-07-14 17:01:00") but fro this data I only need the hours part (17 only) so I'm trying to substring it to get only that part, I added that function:

```
def substr(strtime):
    strtime = strtime.Substr(strtime, 0, 3)
    return substr(strtime)
```

And I'nm getting that error meaage
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Substr'

Does any body have an idea about how to fix it?

Comment: What makes you think that strings have a `Substr` function? Besides that, your function calls itself. I recommend reading a basic Python tutorial.

Answer (score 6):

Strings in python can be treated as char arrays so you can access like this:

```
myStr=strtime[0:3]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `datetime` module.

**Ex:**

```
import datetime
def substr(strtime):
    strtime = datetime.datetime.strptime(strtime, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return strtime.strftime("%H")

print( substr( "2017-07-14 17:01:00")  )
```

*If you do not want to use datetime module you can do.*

```
def substr(strtime):
    return strtime[11:13]
```

**Output:**

```
17
```